# How do I use Vim's escape() with <C-R> as its first argument?

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

My goal is to select several words in Vim's visual mode (well, neovim in my case), press leader+L and let `fzf` show search results for the selected string through `:Rg`. I came up with this:

```
vnoremap <expr> <leader>l 'y:<C-U>Rg '. shellescape(escape('<C-R>"', '()[]><')) .'<CR>'
```

Which does work, but when I select the text `options(:modifier)` and trigger a search, the `escape()` command doesn't escape the parentheses and `Rg` fails to return results.

In short, I'm expecting this command to fire:

```
:Rg 'options\(:modifier\)'
```

And I'm getting this instead:

```
:Rg 'options(:modifier)'
```

I'm guessing I can't use `<C-R>` in this context, but I can't seem to figure out why?

---

**UPDATE**: Thanks to a helpful reply from user [D. Ben Knoble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4400820/d-ben-knoble) indicating I could drop  and construct the mapping differently, I ended up with this, solving my problem:

```
vnoremap <leader>l "ky:exec 'Rg '. shellescape(escape(@k, '()[]{}?.'))<CR>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need to—all registers are available as variable’s prefixed with `@` (all are readable except `@_`, most are writable, I think).

So instead of `<C-R>"`, use `@"`

Comment: @dbenknoble Using `@"` does apply the `escape()` call correctly now, thank you. However, it seems to take the value of the previous yank instead of the current one.

Comment: @DaveLens that’s because of the order of evaluation: when you trigger an expr mapping, the expr is evaluated to produce the right hand side, and then that key sequence is performed. You have two options: escape the control-r (you need double quotes and a backslash before <), or construct the mapping without using expr.

Comment: @DBenKnoble After an excessive read of the help page on registers and some trial and error, I got it working! I opted to mapping without using expr and came up with `vnoremap <leader>l "ky:exec 'Rg '. shellescape(escape(@k, '()[]{}?.'))<CR>`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!